# end of the inserted text in jsPdf

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf

I'm trying to insert a text after a table, but number of lines can vary so I want to calculate the height of the text to know if I need to add a page or not.

The text has a maxWidth.

How can I do it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:
If you are using jsPDF just set desired element for print to `min-height: 840px` , in this way if text is longer automaticly will add new page.

You can simply select and get the height of text element on print.